# Scroll UITextView to Show New Text Added Programatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextview, ios7.1

I have a `UITextView` that I *only* add text to, programatically. For example, pasting text that's on the pasteboard. So I've got the following:

```
UITextView* _pastedText;
_pastedText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:pastedTextFrame];
_pastedText.editable = NO;
_pastedText.selectable = NO;
```

When I add new text (programatically) the text view will scroll to the top (without animation). I'm not triggering this scroll; I assume it's default behaviour?

How do I get the text view to scroll so that the new next is in view?

**Additional info**

I've seen lots of related questions/answers on here. I've posted this question because, with the code below, I'm seeing undesired behaviour. This is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)addText:(NSString*)text
{
    NSString* textToAdd = text;

    BOOL previouslyHadText = _pastedText.text.length > 0;
    if (previouslyHadText) {
        textToAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", _pastedText.text, text];
    }

    NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = _lineSpacing;
    NSDictionary *attribute = @{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                                 NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0] };

    _pastedText.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textToAdd attributes:attribute];

    if (previouslyHadText) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(_pastedText.text.length - 1, 1);
        [_pastedText scrollRangeToVisible:range];
    }
}
```

I have some success with this, but see the following bugs/problems:

**Scenario 1:**

- Text view has text in it, top of content is visible
- I add text and it successfully scrolls to view the new text
- I manually scroll the textview
- After the manual scroll, if I add more new text, the text view **first** scrolls to the top (as per the original behaviour), **and then**  my explicit scroll, scrolls to the bottom

**Scenario 2:**

- Text view starts empty
- Add new text that would require the text view to scroll; no scrolls occurs
- I manually scroll the text view
- Add new text; now the scrolling does occur, but suffers the go-to-top-first descrive in scenario 1

How do I (do I need to?) disable the *implicit* scrolling (scenario 1)?

What do I need to do so that my scrolling happens before manually scrolling the view (scenario 2)?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're trying to do something very similar to what I'm trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570186/how-to-adjust-contentoffset-of-uitextview-when-updating-text-dynamically) though you're using scrollRangeToVisible to do the scrolling rather than playing with the contentOffset.

Nonetheless a potential solution to your issue w/ the TextView automatically scrolling after you add text to it, is to disable setScrollEnabled while you update your TextView. Have you already tried that?

```
[_pastedText setScrollEnabled:NO];
    _pastedText.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textToAdd attributes:attribute];
[_pastedText setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried `setScrollEnabled`... but I actually think it's not a scrolling issue. I'm replacing the `UITextView`s content, so I think it's being completely updated. I've switched to using `contentOffset` - as outlined in my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450407/waiting-for-uitextview-to-finish-updating-text-ios-7-1  I still think there is a bug in `UITextView`, but for now, I've got a workaround. Thanks.