# Waiting for UITextView to Finish Updating Text (iOS 7.1)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uitextview, nsnotificationcenter

I'm programatically updating the `attributedText` of a `UITextView`. Following the update I want to call `setContentOffset` so that I can scroll to position the new text.

The problem I'm having is that there's a delay in the text view updating its text.

With the following code the debug log outputs the same value:

```
- (void)appendToTextView:(NSString*)text
{
    CGFloat bottomOfCurrentContent = _pastedText.contentSize.height;
    NSLog(@"Bottom of content, before = %f", bottomOfCurrentContent);

    NSString* textViewText = text;

    BOOL previouslyHadText = _pastedText.text.length > 0;
    if (previouslyHadText) {
        textViewText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", _pastedText.text, textViewText];
    }

    NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = _lineSpacing;
    NSDictionary *attribute = @{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                                 NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0] };

    _pastedText.attributedText = [[ NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textViewText attributes:attribute];

    if (previouslyHadText) {
        CGFloat bottomOfNewContent = _pastedText.contentSize.height;
        NSLog(@"Bottom of content, after = %f", bottomOfNewContent);
        // Set content offset...
    }
}
```

**E.g., output:**

```
2014-05-03 21:52:57.181 thisApp[7011:60b] Bottom of content, before = 244.000000
2014-05-03 21:52:57.182 thisApp[7011:60b] Bottom of content, after = 244.000000
```

If I artificially wait for the text view to complete its update the content is reported as expected...

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGFloat bottomOfNewContent = _pastedText.contentSize.height;
        NSLog(@"Bottom of content, after = %f", bottomOfNewContent);
        // Set content offset...
    });
```

**Output:**

```
2014-05-03 23:12:39.694 thisApp[7050:60b] Bottom of content, before = 244.000000
2014-05-03 23:12:44.698 thisApp[7050:60b] Bottom of content, after = 451.000000
```

So, how do I get updated when the `UITextView`s update has finished?

**Update:**

Based on the suggestion from *indyfromoz*, I can get a callback from the delegate method `textViewDidChangeSelection`, following a programatic update to the text view. However, when that delegate method is called, the text view still hasn't *finished* updating.

If I drop the log statement in there:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{    
    CGFloat newContentHeight = textView.contentSize.height;
    NSLog(@"bottom of new content: %f", newContentHeight);
}
```

The content height is reported the same as it was before the update...

I'm putting this down to a bug with `UITextView`. I'll work around it for now and look at the code again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

After the insertion of the new text in your `UITextView`, you can use `scrollRangeToVisible` (Typically through the `textViewDidChangeSelection` delegate method) to scroll the text view's content. `UITextView` in iOS 7 has some bugs and there is a [good article by Peter discussing this](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2014/fixing-uitextview-on-ios-7/) and [Brent Simmons has a near perfect solution](http://inessential.com/2014/01/07/uitextview_scroll-to-typing_bug) for scrolling content in UITextView.

Comment: Indyfromoz, thanks for the links and the delegate method. I'd tried `textViewDidEndEditing`, though suspected it was for user editing of the text view. Hooking into `textViewDidChangeSelection` does give me the notification, so thanks! I'll try connecting it up and then mark this as the answer. I had also considered the `NSNotification` `UITextViewTextDidEndEditingNotification` - but again I think that's for user editing/keyboard editing of the text view. As for iOS 7 bugs in `UITextView`, I think I've encountered one or two ;) Thanks.

Comment: See update to initial question, think I'm going to have to work around this. Cheers, Gavin